# A simple string manipulation causes Bus Error in Clang Assembler

Tags: assembly, clang, x86-64

The following Clang Assembly program:

```
.intel_syntax
 .global _main
_main:
 push rbp
 mov rbp,rsp
 lea rdi,[rip+helloWorld]
 call _printf
 mov al,'_'
 mov [rip+helloWorld+5],al
 lea rdi,[rip+helloWorld]
 call _printf
 mov rax,0
 pop rbp
 ret
helloWorld:
 .string "Hello world!\n"
```

outputs:

```
Hello world!
Bus error: 10
```

The nearly-equivalent program in Flat Assembler:

```
format binary as 'COM'
org 100h

mov ah,9
lea dx,[hello]
int 21h

mov al,'_'
mov [hello+5],al

mov ah,9
lea dx,[hello]
int 21h

int 20h

hello:
db "Hello world!",10,13,24h
```

outputs:

```
Hello world!
Hello_world!
```

What causes the Bus Error in the former? The Bus Error is supposed to occur when you try to access a memory address that doesn't belong to your program. But that's obviously not the case here: the "printf" function is clearly able to access the string. It just appears that a simple attempt to manipulate the string somehow causes the Bus Error. It's not at all obvious how it could, especially since the nearly-equivalent program works in Flat Assembler.

Comment: Those programs couldn't be any more different. One is 16 bit and runs in DOS, the other is 64 bit and runs in Linux.

Comment: The `.text` section that you put your message into is read-only. Put it into `.data` instead.

Comment: When I put it in ".data", the program doesn't crash, but it outputs "_ello world!" instead of "Hello_world!".

Comment: That should work. I don't have clang here, but works with gcc. Note, you should zero `al` before calling `printf` because that is a varargs function.